# Add rightBarButtonItem on second place Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

I want to add rightBarButtonItem directly to the position of second place because I already have slider menu button on the right side of navigation bar(which is placed by third party framework and I don't have control over it). The following is the screenshot for the same with black area where I want second button for notifications.

[image]

Following is the code using which add it to top of slider menu button:-

```
let backButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "menulist"), for: UIControl.State())
backButton.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
let rightbarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbarButton
```

Slider menu is a third party framework so I don't have any idea how to achieve it.

Please help and suggest some workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append your new item like:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(newButton)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want bar button to be placed directly on secord position because slider menu button is placed by third party framework. so I don't have control over it. Is there any way of setting bar button position?

Comment: So you can append current items `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.append(newButton)` does it solve your question?